# uploading images through form.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

if i upload the image through my admin dashboard, the image will be successfully uploaded, it will appear in media folder in my project directory i specified in settings.py. but if i upload an image through form.py as a user, every other field is saved except for the image field. I've tried most of the solutions on stackoverflow, dont know why mine ain't working.

while debugging i made mainimage a required field, so it threw this error: *ValueError: The view products.views.products didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'mainimage', 'category', 'preview_text',
                  'detail_text', 'price','Quantity']
        labels = {
            'name': _('Product name'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'name': _('be specific eg Tomatoes, Rice'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'name': {
                'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import ProductForm
from .models import Product
# Create your views here.
def products(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ProductForm()
        return render(request, 'products/add_product.html',{'forms':form})
    else:
        # imagefield is different from other
        # fields and it needs to be handles properly
        # data fetched from imagefield would be stored
        # in request.FILES object.
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                mainimage = form.cleaned_data.get('mainimage')
                category = form.cleaned_data.get('category')
                preview_text = form.cleaned_data.get('preview_text')
                detail_text = form.cleaned_data.get('detail_text')
                price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
                Quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
                obj = Product.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    mainimage = mainimage,
                    category = category,
                    preview_text = preview_text,
                    detail_text = detail_text,
                    price = price,
                    Quantity = Quantity
                )
                obj.save()


                # form.save()
                return redirect('/products/')
        else:
            form = ProductForm()
            return render(request, 'add_product.html', {'form': form})
```

**add_product**

```
{% extends "plugs/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h4>Add a Product</h4>
<form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
<!--                    {{form_store.store_name|as_crispy_field}}-->
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                            {{ forms.name|as_crispy_field }}

                        </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"  >
                            {{ forms.mainimage|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          {{ forms.category|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">

                            {{ forms.preview_text|as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ forms.detail_text|as_crispy_field }}
<!--                        {{ forms.price|as_crispy_field }}-->

                        {{ forms.Quantity|as_crispy_field }}


                        </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-database"></i>Submit</button>
                </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/media/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 300)
    primaryCategory = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    mainimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preview_text = models.TextField(max_length = 200, verbose_name='Preview Text')
    detail_text = models.TextField(max_length= 1000, verbose_name='Detail text')
    price = models.FloatField()
    Quantity = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='1 quantity')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('plugs.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
    path('home/', include('cart.urls')),
    # path('products/', include('products.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                         document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: dont use "#" , specify an action, it may help

Comment: thanks, I've done that. the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

ok better change your view to

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                instance.mainimage = form.cleaned_data['mainimage']
                instance.category = form.cleaned_data['category']
                instance.preview_text = form.cleaned_data['preview_text']
                instance.detail_text = form.cleaned_data.get['detail_text']
                instance.price = form.cleaned_data['price']
                instance.Quantity = form.cleaned_data['Quantity']
                instance.save()
```

Comment: i updated my post view, it threw this error: AttributeError: *'ProductForm' object has no attribute 'request'*

Comment: it raised this error *TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable*

Comment: form.cleaned_data.get['detail_text'] typo here ... fix it.

Comment: it ran, but still couldn't upload a picture. i went to the admin, no picture found

Comment: can you try request.FILES['mainimage'] instead of form.cleaned_data['mainimage']

Answer (score 0):

Is your MEDIA_DIR set in your settings.py?

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/media/')
```

Comment: yes, if i upload an image from admin to is save in the folder. I doubt if the problem is from there.

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: The view products.views.products didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Means your somewhere in your views you are not returning an Http response. Try indenting last line of your view to at same level as else. It may resolve